# What is the significance in an alpha-helix being right-handed or left-handed?

Tags: proteins, protein-binding, protein-folding, protein-interaction

Why is that often when alpha-helices are discussed, it is also mentioned their direction - right-handed (clockwise) or left-handed (anti-clockwise)?

I have heard that left-handed alpha-helices are usually less stable, but I'm sure there is more to it than that?

Comment: A quick search sent me here: https://www.quora.com/Why-are-most-alpha-helices-in-proteins-right-handed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some experimental and modelling observations suggests, folding energy for right handed in more favorable. You can find more detailed answer to this question [here](http://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=3802).